# Scraping a pretty typical block of text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this block:

```
<b>Address:</b></br>
First Line</br>
Second Line</br>
City, State Zip</br>
 <b>Phone: 718-555-2121</br>
 <b>Fax:</b> 718-555-1212</br>
 <b>Email:</b> ex@example.com</br>
```

Reliably into a dict.

```
dict = {
    'address':'First Line\n Second Line\n City, State Zip\n',
    'phone':'718-555-2121',
    'Fax:':'718-555-1212',
    'Email:':'ex@example.com',
    }
```

If I look for bold and then next_sibling, I get the phone number, fax and email just fine, but the address is a handful of siblings.

```
for nut in soup.find_all("b"):
    print nut,
    try:
        print nut.next_sibling.tag
    except:
        print nut.next_sibling
```

If I look for bold and then next_siblings, I get all the siblings:

```
for nut in soup.find_all("b"):
    print nut
    for s,sibling in enumerate(nut.next_siblings):
        print s, (repr(sibling))
```

Is there a clean way (`while`?) to say keep assembling next_siblings until you get to a bold sibling?

Comment: Are the address lines always the first three lines after `<b>Address:</b>`?

Comment: I would just punt the whole parent element into a string and use regular expressions to grab the pieces I want.

Comment: @kreativitea You have to work on the whole "answers in the comments" thing.

Comment: @That1Guy Unfortunately, no. The address can be 3-6 lines.

Comment: @Amanda Ah but yes, this time it was a suggestion, not an answer!  I can try and code something up if you want.  But this way, you can code it, I can work, and I'll come upvote you when you come post it as a response. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I worked on it a little bit using your method, and I came up with this.

```
b = soup.b
results = []
result = str()
while b != None:
    try:
        if b.name == 'b':
            results.append(result)
            result = b.text
    except AttributeError:
        result = result + b
    b = b.nextSibling
results.append(result)
```

Kind of ugly, I think.  But, it should be pretty easy to follow.

`b.nextSibling` returns two different kinds of objects, `NavigableString` (in the case where it's a `<\br>`) or a `Tag`, in the case where it's a new `<b>` element.  `.name` is a valid method of a `Tag`, but not of a `NavigatableString`.  Using that, you can distinguish between the two cases, using a try/except clause.  `b.nextSibling` returns `None` when the elements are exhausted, and the loop cuts out.  The final line appends the last object.

Comment: I mostly just moved on, but this gets at the gist of it.